# Extracting data from 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, slice

I have got a 3d matrix in the following form: `3x3x46`

Is there a simple way that I can extract the a matrix with the 3rd row and first two columns?

For the example here which is `3x3x3` I would like to extract

```
0.2710    0.5965
0.0280    0.3255
0.2285    0.4695
```

Here is a sample:

```
val(:,:,1) =

   -0.0492    0.6831    0.1291
   -0.4870    0.2893    0.2642
    0.2710    0.5965    0.8940


val(:,:,2) =

   -0.2316    1.4371    2.5806
   -2.4170    1.2168    6.4721
    0.0280    0.3255    0.0730


val(:,:,3) =

   -0.0881    0.9226    0.3146
   -1.0027    0.8638    1.0925
    0.2285    0.4695    0.6715
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's dissect what you're asking:

> a matrix with the 3rd row

```matlab
val(3, ?, ?)
```

> and first two columns

```matlab
val(3, 1:2, ?)  % or [1,2]
```

As for the 3<sup>rd</sup> index, you want to do this for all "slices", so you should use [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), which means "all" in this context:

```matlab
val(3, 1:2, :)
```

As [explained by obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219777/3372061), this results in a `1×2×3` array, whereas you wanted a `3×2(×1)` - so we need to reorder the dimensions:

```matlab
out = permute( val(3, 1:2, :), [3,2,1] );
```

Comment: A perfectly explained answer step-by-step :) Great

Answer (score 1):

You can use a classic linear index:

```
extract = val(3,1:2,:)
```

But of course it will produce a 1x2x3 matrice, with a leading singleton dimension. You can remove the singleton dimension with:

```
extract = squeeze(val(3,1:2,:))
```

En finally transpose your result to obtain the expected output:

```
extract = squeeze(val(3,1:2,:)).'
```

Comment: Instead of `squeeze` + `.'` one can simply `permute`.